# How do I parse XML from NetworkStream via ReadAsync of XmlReader in C#?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, streaming, async-await

I am trying to read in XML that I receive as `NetworkStream` from an OpenFire server via `BeginRead` of the `NetworkStream` class in C# with following code (I call it every 1024 bytes to give it more XML parts which are saved in `data` (which is `byte[]`)).

```
using (var r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)), 
                                new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
{                    
    while (await r.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (r.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                Console.WriteLine(r.LocalName);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                Console.WriteLine(await r.GetValueAsync());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The 'incomplete' XML I am receiving looks like follows.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="blah" id="d6c0a0b8" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
<stream:features>
<starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls>
<mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism>
<mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
<mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism>
<mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism>
</mechanisms>
<compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress">
<method>zlib</method>
</compression>
<auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/>
<register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/>
</stream:features>
```

I am getting 2 exceptions.

- System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character
- System.Xml.XmlException: 'stream' is an undeclared prefix

Why am I getting these exceptions? How do I fix them?

I tried using `ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment` but this seems to have nothing to do with it.

Maybe I am using `XmlReader` and its `ReadAsync` method completely wrong? Would it be better to read directly from the `NetworkStream` (if this is the case how is it done correctly)?

Currently I am calling the above code like follows every 1024 bytes (size of the buffer).

```
private void EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    ...
    HandleXMLInput(buffer, nBytes);
    ...
}
```

**Update:**

I just realized that no BeginReceive/EndReceive is needed at all. It is sufficient to just open the `NetworkStream` and then wait for data coming from the network in `AsyncRead` (woohoo! ;)). The following code sums it up.

```
socket.BeginConnect(endPoint, new AsyncCallback(EndConnect), null);
private void EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    ...
    socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);

    networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket, false);

    HandleXMLInput();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of directly using `Socket`, you can use `TcpClient`. With that, you can do something like `await client.ConnectAsync(address, port); NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are decoding the stream elsewhere then feeding it in chunks to XmlReader. Because each time, you're creating a new XmlReader for every chunk, after the first chunk, you'll be feeding broken Xml to a process that expects a well-formed document.

Why not save a whole bunch of coding and heartache by reading the stream directly?

```
using(var r = XmlReader.Create(myNetworkStream))
{                    
    //await r.ReadAsync() only returns false at the end of the document
    //so this loop will read the whole document
    while (await r.ReadAsync()) 
    {
        switch (r.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                Console.WriteLine(r.LocalName);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                Console.WriteLine(await r.GetValueAsync());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

to be clear: you don't need to do any additional reading of the stream before passing it to the XmlReader. The reader takes care of all the read operations on your behalf when you call `ReadAsync`.

Comment: A question to reading directly from the stream: am I suppose to call my parsing function (the one with `AsyncRead`) each time after `EndReceive`? Or is there some magic around that will continue reading until the XML is closed?

Comment: You don't need to involve yourself with BeginXXX/EndXXX methods. These are old-style async methods (APM) that you really don't need to bring into the mix when using async/await. See my updated example.

Comment: For replacing BeginXXX and/or EndXXX in network programming: do you mean like in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx?

Comment: @TonyStark You don't need that here at all. Just use the code in this answer and it will work.

Comment: @svick: I just realized it and updated my question with the code.